# How to manage session in Oracle JET application

Tags: session, oracle-jet

How can I manage the session in Oracle JET application.

I've been working on small pilot application where I need to check if the user is logged in on every request.

I didn't find any resource on the same as the framework is recently published by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

JET uses web sessions if you configure it as a web application. So authentication would be managed by the Web server.

Frank

Comment: Whether session can be maintained for Mobile Application using Oracle JET?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the client nature of JS source, there's no session on the JET side of your application, Session is a (HTTP) browser feature. You might handle session exactly the way you did with a pure JavaScript, JQuery, Angular or everything else application.

Answer (score 0):

There may be two ways to do it

> 1. Use web server to manage the sessions.
> 2. You can store session values (some data after login REST API call) in local storage or sessions storage based on your need. For managing
>      session you can check in your app controller and redirect based on
>      that.

Hope this help, please let me know if you faced any problem. I have recently implemented session in Oracle JET based on the above points.

Comment: Now I realized that I was the first one to ask Oracle-JET question on SO :), btw I didn't pursue the Oracle JET then, but now after 3 years the framework is much matured and has real life use case with many production enabled application as well as utilization by oracle, Again I am back to the roots. I would like to seek your help if you've documented you learning anywhere.

Comment: Regarding the login session, can you please elaborate how do you manage it ? As I've background of MVC apps development mostly using ADF or OAF, I would like to know how its managed in JavaScript frameworks

Comment: @ITppl Please use my directions given in answer or I will create a post with detailed information and share it with you again.